# How to kill an app running in background using another app in ios swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background, kill

I have an app which is already running in the background, how can I kill that app from background using another application in ios?

Comment: One iOS app can not kill another. Would you really want some other app to be able to kill your app? "Food Fight!" ;-)

Comment: one ios app can launch another. y not kill?? Coz I am able to trigger the app to background using another app.

Comment: An iOS app cannot explicitly launch another.  An iOS app can send a request to a URL to which an app responds.  The app that is opening is allowing itself to be opened.  The app making the request is not forcing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone killing background apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020691/iphone-killing-background-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't do that. 
Any iOS apps can't kill any other app; you can open another app but you need to use a custom URL request.

From Apple documentation:

> Apps communicate only indirectly with other apps on a device

and you can't say to another app "kill yourself thank you", because you can't kill any app, also your app! You not able to add a button in iOS (just for example) for kill the app.

For more info look at [Inter-App Communication documentation by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2).