# Mac OS X: Getting detailed process information (specifically its launch arguments) for arbitrary running applications using its PID

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, process, command-line-arguments, pid

I am trying to detect when particular applications are launched.

Currently I am using `NSWorkspace`, registering for the "did launch application" notification. I also use the `runningApplications` method to get apps that are currently running when my app starts.

For most apps, the name of the app bundle is enough. I have a plist of "known apps" that I cross check with the name of that passed in the notification.

This works fine until you come across an app that acts as a proxy for launching another application using command line arguments.

Example: The newly released Portal on the Mac doesn't have a dedicated app bundle. Steam can create a shortcut, which serves as nothing more than to launch the `hl2_osx` app with the `-game` argument and `portal` as it's parameter.

Since more Source based games are heading to the Mac, I imagine they'll use the same method to launch, effectively running the `hl2_osx` app with the `-game` argument.

Is there a nice way to get a list of the arguments (and their parameters) using a Cocoa API?

`NSProcessInfo` comes close, offering an `-arguments' method, but only provides information for its own process...

`NSRunningApplication` offers the ability to get information about arbitrary apps using a PID, but no command line args...

Is there anything that fills the gap between the two?

I'm trying not to go down the route of spawning an `NSTask` to run `ps -p [pid]` and parsing the output... I'd prefer something more high level.

Comment: The docs say NSApplication will only track "User applications" and not other processes. I need indicate in (system-preferences) UI  when my daemon is running/not running, and I don't know how...  Can I somehow get this rudimentary information using one of the higher level Obj-C APIs? If not - can you spare a snippet on parsing ps output for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use whatever `ps` uses, though it isn't cocoa based. According to [Singh](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161748/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/procfs/), `ps` is based on kvm and sysctl calls. Pouring over the [source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-138.1/ps/ps.c), the pertinant calls seem to be [`kvm_openfiles`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.4-intel/man3/kvm_openfiles.3.html), [`kvm_getprocs`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.4-intel/man3/kvm_getprocs.3.html) and `kvm_getargv`. To get the command line arguments, first call `kvm_openfiles` to get access to the kernel memory space, then use `kvm_getprocs` to get kernel process info, then `kvm_getargv`.

The use of `sysctl` in `ps` seems less relevant to your goal; it's used to get other information, such as the group ID and parent proces ID. The particular sysctl name used is `{CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_which, flags}`, where *which* specifies a process filter (e.g. `ALL`, `PID`) and *flags* are arguments for the filter (the details are in the [`sysctl`](https://web.archive.org/web/20100129035250/http://developer.apple.com:80/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html) man page).

OS X doesn't have support procfs, but Singh developed a [FUSE based version](https://web.archive.org/web/20200816070829/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter11/procfs/), released under GPLv2. If you bundle it with your application, you'll have to release it under GPLv2 as well. Most of MacFUSE is released under a [BSD-style license](https://code.google.com/archive/p/macfuse/source), so it can be distributed with your app without making it open source (fusefs/fuse_nodehash.c is released under Apple's open source license, but it also allows linking to closed source apps).

The question "[Get other process' argv in OS X using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210397/get-other-process-argv-in-os-x-using-c)" should be of use, as it has sample code using kvm and sysctl. [TN 2050 "Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2050/) may also be of use to you.

Comment: The `kvm_` functions are the "noop versions" I refer to in my answer.  They do not work.  (`sysctl` does, but it's not a public interface.)  The `kvm_` man pages and `kvm.h` were present in 10.4 (as you linked to) but are gone in 10.5+.  Note that all references to `kvm` in the `ps` source are guarded by `#ifndef __APPLE__` or `#if FIXME` - my guess is that the developers plan to implement `kvm_*` in the future but haven't had time (and may never).

Answer (score 4):

Nope - running `ps` is your best bet.  Standard process info interfaces aren't supported on OS X (noop versions were provided in OS X 10.4, but removed thereafter) and the private interfaces are likely to change between OS X revisions.

If you're willing to lock yourself into a single OS X version, all the source is available, for example for [ps](http://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-138.1/ps/ps.c) or [libproc](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/darwin/libproc.c); you'll also need to run as root.