# How to programatically get uid from pid in osx using c++?

Tags: c++, macos, unix, process

Given a pid, I want to find the owner of the process (as uid). Is there a way to get this in osx (or any unix) using C++?

Google didn't help. 'ps' is able to do it; so I assume there should be a way to get it programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a way to programatically do this without parsing the output of 'ps'

```
uint getUidUsingSysctl(uint pid)
{
    struct kinfo_proc *sProcesses = NULL, *sNewProcesses;
    int    aiNames[4];
    size_t iNamesLength;
    int    i, iRetCode, iNumProcs;
    size_t iSize;

    iSize = 0;
    aiNames[0] = CTL_KERN;
    aiNames[1] = KERN_PROC;
    aiNames[2] = KERN_PROC_ALL;
    aiNames[3] = 0;
    iNamesLength = 3;

    iRetCode = sysctl(aiNames, iNamesLength, NULL, &iSize, NULL, 0);

    /* allocate memory and populate info in the  processes structure */
    do
    {
        iSize += iSize / 10;
        sNewProcesses = (kinfo_proc *)realloc(sProcesses, iSize);

        if (sNewProcesses == 0)
        {
            if (sProcesses)
                free(sProcesses);
            /* could not realloc memory, just return */
            return -1;
        }
        sProcesses = sNewProcesses;
        iRetCode = sysctl(aiNames, iNamesLength, sProcesses, &iSize, NULL, 0);
    } while (iRetCode == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

    iNumProcs = iSize / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

    for (i = 0; i < iNumProcs; i++)
    {
        if (sProcesses[i].kp_proc.p_pid == pid) 
        {
            return sProcesses[i].kp_eproc.e_ucred.cr_uid;
        }

    }

    /* clean up and return to the caller */
    free(sProcesses);

    return -1;
}
```

Note: There might be a better way to get 'kinfo_proc' instead of iterating through all process.

Comment: perhaps using sysctl with CTL_KERN + KERN_PROC + `KERN_PROC_PID` instead of KERN_PROC_ALL

Answer (score 5):

Solution from Indhu helped me on my way, so I would like to post my own.

UID from PID with pure C:

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

uid_t uidFromPid(pid_t pid)
{
    uid_t uid = -1;

    struct kinfo_proc process;
    size_t procBufferSize = sizeof(process);

    // Compose search path for sysctl. Here you can specify PID directly.
    const u_int pathLenth = 4;
    int path[pathLenth] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, pid};

    int sysctlResult = sysctl(path, pathLenth, &process, &procBufferSize, NULL, 0);

    // If sysctl did not fail and process with PID available - take UID.
    if ((sysctlResult == 0) && (procBufferSize != 0))
    {
        uid = process.kp_eproc.e_ucred.cr_uid;
    }

    return uid;
}
```

No excess allocation, no loops.

Comment: I know it's been awhile, but I'm curious if anyone else ran into the same thing? For some PIDs (for a process that is still running) the call to `sysctl` returns success (or 0) but it sets the result in its 4th parameter (or your `procBufferSize`) to 0. What could be causing it?

Answer (score 3):

The source for the ps command, reveals that there is a function called `get_proc_stats` defined in [proc/readproc.h](http://astrophoenix.com/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.cgi/free/diff/2fc0bb98959d/procps/proc/readproc.h) that (among other things) returns the `real user name(UID)` & `Effective user name(EUID)` for a given pid.

You need to do install `libproc-dev` to get this function. and then you can do:

```
#include <proc/readproc.h>
void printppid(pid_t pid) 
{
    proc_t process_info;
    get_proc_stats(pid, &process_info);
    printf("Real user of the process[%d] is [%s]\n", pid, process_info.ruser);
}
```

compile it with `gcc the-file.c -lproc`.

Once you have the real user name you can use [getpwnam()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam) and [getgrnam()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getgrnam) functions to get the uid.

Comment: Where do I get libproc from? I tried building it from 'http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-78/libproc/'. But, it seems to be using some private headers like '#include <CoreSymbolication/CoreSymbolicationPrivate.h>'

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [how ps does it](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/bin/ps/ps.c.html). It looks like it uses the [kvm_getprocs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.4-intel/man3/kvm_getprocs.3.html) function.

However, it's much more portable (you said "any unix", but e.g. the Linux and Solaris way is to look in the `/proc` filesystem - and other unixes may have different APIs) to just parse the output of ps (`ps -o user= -p (pid)` for example, to eliminate any extraneous output) than to do any system-specific process stuff

Comment: Looks like Apple is phasing out the kvm interface. http://www.clusterresources.com/pipermail/torquedev/2006-December/000395.html

Answer (score 2):

There's not a portable way to do this.  On Mac OS, you've got to use poorly documented `sysctl` interfaces:  see [this previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838190/mac-os-x-getting-detailed-process-information-specifically-its-launch-arguments).  (As other commenters pointed out, on Linux you can use proc.  On FreeBSD, you should be able to use `kvm_getfiles`, although this is not available on Mac OS.)

Your best bet is to use the source for Apple's [`ps`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-138.1/ps/ps.c) as a jumping-off point for grabbing process data and then you'll be able to use `getpwuid(3)` once you have the uid.

Comment: Looks like I will have to stick to parsing ps output until Apple comes up with a documented API to do this.