# Can I get the the UID of a given PID using C

Tags: c, process, pid, uid

I want to get the user ID of a given process ID using C

How can I do it?

Any insight appreciated ;)

Comment: There's a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6457682/960195) that might prove useful.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing, Tutorial or Consulting Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496) ... Or more succinctly, [What Have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'm very sorry and thanks for your advice. Hope you forgive me as a newer. And I will reform myself endlessly. So, thanks all of you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `procfs` file system, then the effective user ID of the files in `/proc/<pid>` are that of the user.