# OSX: proc_pidinfo returns 0 for other user's processes

Tags: c, macos

I need to get some information (PID, UID, GID, process name) about running processes on Mac OSX. I tried `proc_pidinfo`. For my own processes it works fine. However, for processes owned by other users, 0 is returned. There's no documentation for this function, but according to [information found on Internet](http://vinceyuan.github.io/wrong-info-from-procpidinfo/), it's supposed to return number of bytes written into provided buffer. Calling this function on other user's processes returns 0, which means that no information was provided.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <libproc.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    struct proc_bsdinfo proc;

    if (argc == 2)
        pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    else
        pid = getpid();

    int st = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDTBSDINFO, 0,
                         &proc, PROC_PIDTBSDINFO_SIZE);

    if (st != PROC_PIDTBSDINFO_SIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get process info");
        return 1;
    }
    printf(" pid: %d\n", (int)proc.pbi_pid);
    printf("ppid: %d\n", (int)proc.pbi_ppid);
    printf("comm: %s\n",      proc.pbi_comm);
    printf("name: %s\n",      proc.pbi_name);
    printf(" uid: %d\n", (int)proc.pbi_uid);
    printf(" gid: %d\n", (int)proc.pbi_gid);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this program yields:

```
 $ ./pidinfo
 pid: 30519
ppid: 8434
comm: pidinfo
name: pidinfo
 uid: 501
 gid: 20
 $ ./pidinfo 1
Cannot get process info
 $ sudo ./pidinfo 1
 pid: 1
ppid: 0
comm: launchd
name: launchd
 uid: 0
 gid: 0
```

That's strange, because I can get all this information from `ps(1)`. But then I checked that both `ps` and `top` on OSX are SUID binaries, which would be in line with `proc_pidinfo` behavior:

```
 $ ls -l `which ps` `which top`
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  51008  5 maj 08:06 /bin/ps
-r-sr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  87952  5 maj 08:05 /usr/bin/top
```

But then, Activity Monitor works without SUID.

So, my question is, why `proc_pidinfo` provides information only about my own processes? Can I make it give me information about other processes? If not, how can I get this information without parsing `ps(1)` output?

Comment: In the past, Activity Monitor did use a SUID tool, though this has been changed over to using launch daemons running as `root`: `/usr/libexec/sysmond`, and possibly also `/usr/libexec/systemstatsd`...

Comment: I think that if you ran `proc_pidinfo` under root privilege, you'll be able to get info for all processes.

Comment: If I run my program with `sudo`, it works - see my example. But I don't want to run my program as root.

Answer (score 6):

I found that macOS Mojave (version 10.14.4) had `struct proc_bsdshortinfo`, which is a subset of `struct proc_bsdinfo`. You can get other user's processes without SUID by using it instead of `struct proc_bsdinfo`.

Well, I don't know from which version it is available.

**edited:** It is available since at least macOS 10.10.5 (Yosemite).
**edited again:** It may be available since Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) because tmux uses `struct proc_bsdshortinfo` if `__MAC_10_7` is defined. See [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/e6ee3e9504e0abc9014e1b20ac6a9c43dd6145fb/osdep-darwin.c#L40-L41).

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <libproc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    struct proc_bsdshortinfo proc;

    if (argc == 2)
        pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    else
        pid = getpid();

    int st = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDT_SHORTBSDINFO, 0,
                         &proc, PROC_PIDT_SHORTBSDINFO_SIZE);

    if (st != PROC_PIDT_SHORTBSDINFO_SIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get process info\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf(" pid: %d\n", (int)proc.pbsi_pid);
    printf("ppid: %d\n", (int)proc.pbsi_ppid);
    printf("comm: %s\n",      proc.pbsi_comm);
    //printf("name: %s\n",      proc.pbsi_name);
    printf(" uid: %d\n", (int)proc.pbsi_uid);
    printf(" gid: %d\n", (int)proc.pbsi_gid);

    return 0;
}
```

This program prints:

```
$ ./pidinfo 
 pid: 3025
ppid: 250
comm: pidinfo
 uid: 501
 gid: 20
$ ./pidinfo 1
 pid: 1
ppid: 0
comm: launchd
 uid: 0
 gid: 0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use :

```
int proc_listpids(uint32_t type, uint32_t typeinfo, void *buffer, int buffersize);
```

combinated to proc_pidinfo to get many others pids informations like :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <libproc.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <mach-o/ldsyms.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void procpid(pid_t pid)
{ struct proc_bsdinfo proc;
  int st = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDTBSDINFO, 0, &proc, PROC_PIDTBSDINFO_SIZE);
  printf("name: %s\n", proc.pbi_name);
}

void pidlist(void)
{ int bufsize = proc_listpids(PROC_ALL_PIDS, 0, NULL, 0);
  pid_t pids[2 * bufsize / sizeof(pid_t)];
  bufsize = proc_listpids(PROC_ALL_PIDS, 0, pids, sizeof(pids));
  size_t num_pids = bufsize / sizeof(pid_t);
  int i = 0;
  while (i < num_pids)
  { printf("pid[%d]::%d\n", i, pids[i]);
    procpid(pids[i]);
    printf("\n-------------------------------\n\n");
    i += 1; }}

int main(void)
{ pidlist();
  return(42); }
```