# Get PPid from specific pid in C

Tags: c, linux, process, pid, low-level

I want to find a way to get the ppid of a specific pid only using C low-level function.
I know there is a way with bash commands, like "ps" etc, but I want to do it only in C language.

Comment: On linux, you can get it and a bunch of other information from parsing `/proc/PID/status`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't find any PID folder in /proc/ (my pc is running Ubuntu 22)

Comment: ... uh, PID is of course the pid of the process you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as you expect. I used pid = 373 which is my current **/usr/sbin/cron**. It properly reports PPID of 1 (init):

```
% ./getppid
PPid = 1
```

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXBUF      (BUFSIZ * 2)

int main () {
    int ppid, pid = 373;  // my current cron pid
    char buf[MAXBUF];
    char procname[32];  // Holds /proc/4294967296/status\0
    FILE *fp;

    snprintf(procname, sizeof(procname), "/proc/%u/status", pid);
    fp = fopen(procname, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        size_t ret = fread(buf, sizeof(char), MAXBUF-1, fp);
        if (!ret) {
            perror("Error reading file: ");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            buf[ret++] = '\0';  // Terminate it.
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    char *ppid_loc = strstr(buf, "\nPPid:");
    if (ppid_loc) {
        ppid = sscanf(ppid_loc, "\nPPid:%d", &ppid);
        if (!ppid || ppid == EOF) {
            perror("scanf:");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("PPid = %d\n", ppid);
    } else {
        printf("Error finding PPid: in status\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```