# Getting ProcessInfo for NSRunningApplication

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, operating-system

I am trying to build an app for MacOS in Swift to log some information about running applications. Some of the information which I would like to get are related to the corresponding processes (user, etc.), but it doesn't seem that I can get them from `NSRunningApplication`. So I was wondering is there any way to get `ProcessInfo`s for `NSRunningApplication`s?
Unfortunately I couldn't find anything in Apple Developer Documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the PID from NSRunningApplication's `processIdentifier` property, and then you can use `sysctl` to get information from the PID. See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20169895/7258538

It's in C, but it should give you the basic idea.