# What is the /proc/self/cmdline / GetCommandLine equivalent on Mac OS X?

Tags: windows, linux, macos, porting

How can I access the command line on Mac OS X without using argc, argv? On Linux, I would simply read `/proc/self/cmdline` or use `GetCommandLine` on Windows, but I can't find the equivalent for Mac OS X.

Comment: You can use `sysctl()` to get at the raw argument space. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210397/get-other-process-argv-in-os-x-using-c/4633191#4633191

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are functions called _NSGetArgv and _NSGetArgc in [crt_externs.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.24/include/crt_externs.h.auto.html). However, wouldn't it be simpler to just store the argc/argv in a variable at the start of main and be portable to all three platforms?

NOTE: These functions are not directly documented, but they are mentioned in the [documentation for NSApplicationMain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/1428499-nsapplicationmain) in the Application Kit Functions Reference, and the related _NSGetEnviron is mentioned in the [environ(7)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/environ.7.html) manpage.