# Query the terminal command that created the Python process in Python

Tags: python, command-line

I have a Python module that I call like this

```
python -m foo.bar arg1 -a foo --some-arg=10
```

And inside the `bar.py` module, I need to query the command that was used to call the module. For example, `get_raw_terminal_command()` would return `"python -m foo.bar arg1 -a foo --some-arg=10"`.

I've seen several posts suggest `import sys; sys.argv` but `sys.argv` fails in multiple ways.

1. `sys.argv` returns the full path the `foo/bar.py` file. I need the raw command for debugging purposes and calling `python /path/to/foo/bar.py` is not the same as calling `python foo.bar`
2. In my production use-case, `sys.argv` is returning `['-c']` instead of the name or path of any Python module. I'm still in the middle of troubleshooting why this is happening but I've already made a case for why `sys.argv` isn't what I'm looking for anyway.

Another popular solution is to use `argparse` to rebuild the command-line input but I can't use it because I don't control how the Python code is being called. The solution must be generic.

Does anyone know how to get the raw command that is used to call a Python script from within the Python script? If possible, the solution should be compatible with Windows.

Comment: Do you mind to edit your answer?
I suggest you to use `argparse` [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead of `sys.argv`.

Comment: The method that's being used to call the Python code isn't always my implementation so I can't use `argparse`. The solution needs to be generic. That said, I'll update my question to exclude `argparse` so people don't post it

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938327/what-is-the-proc-self-cmdline-getcommandline-equivalent-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be compatible with windows, but in GNU/Linux or Solaris (credit: tripleee) you should be able to use /proc/self/cmdline to see exactly how you were called :

```
 Import os

 with open("/proc/self/cmdline") as f:
      print(f.readline())
```

Comment: On my CentOS 7 machine, I had to `[line.replace('\x00', ' ') for line in f.readlines()]` to show spaces between command-line args but it seems to work well. If there's a Windows-specific solution that does the same thing, that'd be perfect

Comment: This also doesn't work on OSX, or a large number of OSes other than Linux and Solaris. The *nix isn't really correct here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs has some further notes.

Comment: Yep, you're right tripleee, updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I found something that may be helpful for Windows users: https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/706727-get-complete-command-line

I'll paste the code again, here:

```
import ctypes

p = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCommandLineA()
print ctypes.c_char_p(p).value
```

The `ctypes` solution worked for me. Another commenter pointed out that pywin32 also has its own flavor:

```
import win32api
print win32api.GetCommandLine ()
```

I didn't test it but that may work better.